# how to connect with azure service bus topic with javascript

Tags: javascript, azure, cordova, azureservicebus

I am creating a mobile application with cordova(phone gap).  I would like my app to talk with an azure service bus to post messages to a topic and read messages from a subscription.

I have found all kinds of details on how to do this with c#, java, python, node.js.  However I haven't found any details on how to do this with pure javascript.

Is this possible?  or must I use Azure mobile services and configure it to communicate with the service bus?

Comment: Did you find any thing out about this problem? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

CORS - Cross-Origin Resource Sharing is now supported in windows azure for storage ,table and queues. So you access the REST api of these from javascript. Topics and Subscriptions are not mentioned here though. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn535601.aspx
Also if you have not already check out Azure notification hubs which may help in your requirement. But mostly for notifications to cross platform devices.

Answer (score 1):

You can use REST API to enqueue messages to a topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh780786.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft provides Service Bus REST API
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh780717.aspx

Microsoft provides two ways to [authenticate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460782.aspx)
1. Azure Active Directory  ([Cordova project sample](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-MultiTarget-Cordova) that uses AD)
2. Using certificates
    If you want to do it using certificates, you need to [generate the .cer and .pem files](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/cloud-services-php-how-to-use-service-management/) and upload the .cer file to your Azure portal -> Settings -> Management Certificate

You can then trigger a http request by passing your .pem file to authenticate your application